# Zabbix error expression vfs.file.regexp

Tags: regex, zabbix

Regex it does not work.
I need to monitor a log in the format log_ddmmyyyy.txt
Test in cmd return error:

```
zabbix_agentd.exe -t "vfs.file.regexp[C:\^log_\d{8}.txt$,Text,,,,1"
**vfs.file.regexp[C:\^log_\d{8}.txt$,Text,,,,1  [m|ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED] [Invalid item key format.]**
```

Trigger in zabbix:

```
{note-sued:vfs.file.regexp[C:\^log_\d{8}.txt$,Text,,,,1].last()}=1
```

Comment: Try `zabbix_agentd.exe -t "vfs.file.regexp[^C:\log_\d{8}\.txt$,Text,,,,1"`.

Comment: I tried also zabbix_agentd.exe -t "vfs.file.regexp[C:\^log_\d{8}\.txt$,Text,,,,1"

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems with the key you are trying on the command line.

The first problem is that, unlike `logrt[]` item, the first parameter to `vfs.file.regexp[]` is not a regexp pattern, but a file name.

The second problem is that the key is not terminated properly: it should have "]" at the end.

Please see [Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) for more information on this item.

Comment: Tested
zabbix_agentd.exe -t "logrt[C:\TEMP\^log_\d{8}.txt$,Teste,,,,1]"

not sucess

Comment: As stated in the answer, the first parameter to vfs.file.regexp[] is not a regexp pattern - it is a file name. Therefore, characters like ^, {, }, $ should not appear there.